# Why must both .a and .dylib files be present when (statically) linking libcurl?

Tags: c++, macos, libcurl, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I built libcurl for macos following the "Apple Platforms" section of https://curl.se/docs/install.html. I link it into my application by adding the resulting libcurl.a file (in the artifacts/lib directory) in my project's frameworks in xcode. It links and works (I can successfully make an https request in my code).

I thought that *just* the libcurl.a file was needed (since my goal is to link statically, and I thought I had accomplished that). However, when I deleted the two .dylib files in that same artifacts/lib directory (specifically libcurl.dylib and libcurl.4.dylib), the link fails with a bunch of undefined symbol errors about SSL, ldap, and others.

My understanding is that one can use either the .a (to link statically) or the .dylib (to link dynamically), but it doesn't make sense to use both. Looking inside my built .app package, there is no libcurl.dylib, or any other dylib, anywhere inside the package, nor in the directory the .app runs in.

So it's behaving as if, when I link to libcurl.a, in the process it somehow grabs some needed code from the libcurl.dylib in the same folder, and can't link without that. *Or* perhaps it needs to see the .dylib during link time for reassurance, but then when I run it uses the macos system copy of libcurl.dylib, and even though mine is a more recent version, they are compatible enough to make things work?

What am I missing?

Comment: I suspect the `libcurl.a` contains thunk routines to the `libcurl.dylib`.

Comment: @Eljay, does that mean that that the .dylib must be present at runtime? On Windows, when you use a DLL, you link with a "stub" library, which I imagine is the same as "thunk" -- meaning it's just a promise that such and such functions will be available in such and such DLL at runtime. But you don't need the DLL nearby at link time. Also, those stub libraries tend to be very small. In my case, libcurl.a is 851 KB and libcurl.4.dylib is 576 KB. So the .a is significantly larger.

Comment: Possibly.  Try using `otool -L a.out` (substitute a.out for whatever your executable is called), and see if your executable depends on the dylib(s).

Comment: @Eljay, ah, I see. Thanks for that tool. Yes, it has libcurl.4.dylib in there, and I see it has an absolute path to it. However, after renaming folders so that absolute path is no longer valid, the app still runs and works. So that seems to mean one of: (a) It doesn't actually use libcurl.4.dylib (because it uses the static code from libcurl.a), or (b) it is able to find a system curl library that satisfies the same need (seems unlikely, but...).

Comment: I also learned that `$ DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 /path/to/my/executable` shows me all libraries that are loaded as the executable runs. In my case it loads "/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib" and "/usr/lib/libcrypto.44.dylib" and "/usr/lib/libssl.46.dylib". Ah, but I see when I make my libcurl.4.dylib available on the expected path, it loads from there, and doesn't load libcrypto or libssl separately. So that confirms that it falls back to system DLLs when the expected DLL is not found. Which is kind of fancy but also could lead to tricky bugs, it seems.

Comment: This article https://medium.com/@donblas/fun-with-rpath-otool-and-install-name-tool-e3e41ae86172 gave me good information on using install_name_tool to add an rpath and use it (i.e., using both of the install_name_tool commands highlighted in that article) to be able to place my libcurl.4.dylib next to the executable within the .app package.

Comment: So I have it working, and I understand everything but the original question: When I link with libcurl.a, and it needs to see libcurl.4.dylib sitting next to it, what exactly is going on? My best understanding is that libcurl.a contains a bunch of code that implements libcurl itself, and libcurl.4.dylib contains a bunch of stuff that it depends on, such as libssl, libcrypto, ldap, and others. The linker wants to see that dylib so it can set up a link to it in the executable. However, the linker does not actually put the dylib into the executable package itself, so you do that yourself.

Comment: I'd have to do an `objdump` on both of the files to see what's in each of them.

Comment: I used `nm -gU`. It showed me that libcurl.a has a bunch of third-party .o files in it, like libcurl_la-openssl.o and libcurl_la-libssh.o. Some of these have symbols and some don't. Perhaps the symbols are from libraries that got compiled with my libcurl build, and the ones without are copied directly from third party libraries. And then libcurl.4.dylib contains a smaller number of functions that seem curl-specific, such as `_curl_easy_init` and `_curl_easy_cleanup`.

Comment: All comments above are false. libcurl.4.dylib is linked to all required libraries. Simply, it's libcurl.a linked with all required libraries. When you link your app with libcurl.a, you also should link the app to all other required libraries, SSL, LDAP,...